# centering rotated multirow in tabulary

Tags: multicolumn, tabulary

I'm having the following table fixed up and working so far. I just can't get the Text in the first two rows to be vertically centered. My guess would be that it's the multicolumn hindering the alignment, but I don't know any other way to get that done.
Just so noone will bother to suggest: I have to imitate an existing table, so I need to have all the vertical lines, despite what good typesetting rules say.

Anyone got an idea how to get the text in the first two rows centered in their respective cells without any more "\vspace" workaround like in the later rows?

```
\documentclass[demo,draft]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}%
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Eisschichtdicke / mm}\\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  & 1,0 & 2,0 & 3,0 & 4,0 & 5,0\\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{{Auslenkung / mm}}} & 1,0 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_1,0}} \\[2pt]
    \cline{2-7}
     & 1,5 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_1,5}} \\[2pt]
    \cline{2-7}
     & 2,0 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_2,0}} \\[2pt]
    \cline{2-7}
     & 2,5 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_2,5}} \\[2pt]
    \cline{2-7}
    \hline
    \end{tabulary}
    \label{Bildmatrix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[demo,draft]{scrreprt}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}%
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|r|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Eisschichtdicke / mm}\\
\cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  & 1,0 & 2,0 & 3,0 & 4,0 & 5,0\\
\hline
{\rotatebox{90}{\makecell{\multirow{5}*{  \vspace{56pt}\hspace{-260pt} Auslenkung / mm}}}}
   \vspace{40pt} 1,0 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}
&{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_1,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_1,0}} 
& \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_1,0}} \\[2pt]
\cline{2-7}
 &   \vspace{40pt} 1,5 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_1,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_1,5}} \\[2pt]
\cline{2-7}
 &   \vspace{40pt} 2,0 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_2,0}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_2,0}} \\[2pt]
\cline{2-7}
 &   \vspace{40pt} 2,5 & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/1mm/V24_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/2mm/V4_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/3mm/V5_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/4mm/V3_2,5}} & \vspace{-6pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Matrix/5mm/V21_2,5}} \\[2pt]
\cline{2-7}
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\label{Bildmatrix}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotatetext]

Comment: yields this result for me: [image](http://i.imgur.com/XP4DHYn.jpg)  
responsible for the broken lines is the \vspace{40pt}, I guess there's a mistake in formatting.

Comment: got it sorted, just an ampersand too much somewhere in the middle.  

how did you determine the amout of hspace/vspace, though?